# set() data is not being passed to view

Tags: arrays, cakephp

**view/plans/index.ctp**

```
<?php debug($plans); ?>
```

**controllers/plans_controller.php (index function)**

```
function index() {
     $plansC = $this->Plan->find('all',
        array('contain' => array('PlanDetail' => array('fields' => array('id',
        'effective_date',
        'expiration_date',
        'active',
        'name',
        'plan_type_id',
        'max_benefit',
        'deductible',
        'preventive',
        'basic',
        'major',
        'ortho',
        'company_id',
        'plan_type_id',
        'plan_detail_note_id'),
        'Company'  => array('fields' => array(
            'id',
            'company_logo_url'
        )),
        'PlanType' => array('fields' => array(
            'id',
            'name'
        ))
    ))));

    debug($plansC);
    $this->set('plans',$this->paginate($planC));
```

Here is a sample index() debug record from the plans_controller.php (as you can see all data is being contained properly using containable):

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Plan] => Array
            (
                [id] => 7
                [created] => 2011-01-10 14:11:40
                [modified] => 2011-02-03 18:35:29
                [plan_detail_id] => 32
                [monthly_cost] => 25.49
                [dental_cost] => 0.00
                [age_id] => 2
                [applicant_id] => 1
                [state_id] => 1
            )

        [PlanDetail] => Array
            (
                [id] => 32
                [effective_date] => 2011-01-10 14:07:00
                [expiration_date] => 2011-01-10 14:07:00
                [active] => 1
                [name] => Classic 1500
                [plan_type_id] => 2
                [max_benefit] => 0.00
                [deductible] => $75/year
                [preventive] => 90%
                [basic] => 75%
                [major] => 50%
                [ortho] => 
N/A


                [company_id] => 4
                [plan_detail_note_id] => 9
                [Company] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4
                        [company_logo_url] => nationwide_logo.png
                    )

                [PlanType] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [name] => Indemnity
                    )

            )

    )
```

The containable data is not being passed. Only data associated with Plan and PlanDetail (no deeper relations than PlanDetail such as Company or Plan type), but the debug in the index controller shows all data being passed! But none of this data is making it into the view debug???

Does anyone know if this is a bug with containable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 8 hours pain, I solved it : ) and I added pagination to boot. I ended up using compact() in place of the baked set().

```
function index() {
    //$this->Plan->find('all'); not needed
    $this->paginate['Plan'] = array('contain' => array('PlanDetail' => array('fields'   => array('id',
        'effective_date',
        'expiration_date',
        'active',
        'name',
        'plan_type_id',
        'max_benefit',
        'deductible',
        'preventive',
        'basic',
        'major',
        'ortho',
        'application_url',
        'company_id',
        'plan_type_id',
        'plan_detail_note_id'),
        'Company'  => array('fields' => array(
            'id',
            'company_logo_url'
        )),
        'PlanType' => array('fields' => array(
            'id',
            'name'
        ))
    )));
    $plans = $this->paginate('Plan');
    $this->set(compact('plans'));
}
```

Comment: compact is not the solution, it's just for the convenience. The problem solver is the $this->paginate() and variable $this->paginate which you've used.

Comment: I must have been doing something wrong but set() was NOT passing data to the view and the switch to compact() made it work as needed. So not sure what was wrong, but its working now and headache gone : )

Answer (score 2):

You must either `paginate` *or* `find`, you can't paginate the found data array. Pagination *is* retrieving data from the database. Replace your `find` call with a `paginate` call. Save the result of the `paginate` call in a variable and `debug` it, your problem is there, not in the `set` call.

Comment: deceze, thank you for the insight. I solved it a moment ago with the below code. I think it might be redundant with the find call, but it is working perfectly now with pagination.

Comment: I removed the find from my below code, and I see exactly what you mean on the paginator call to the model is like a find.